# Correct approach on implementing abstract factory pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, data-access-layer, abstract-factory

I am about to build a data access layer the good old ado.net way. Traditionally I would have built the dal according to a simple repository pattern. But this time I wanna give the Abstract Factory pattern a try because I have read about this pattern in an article lately.

So here I am try to code a dal with the abstract factory pattern. First of let me explain what I got so far. What I wanna know afterwards is whether my approach is the correct way of implementing this pattern and what the advantages are towards the repository approach.

So I wrote the following classes:

```
public abstract class Db
{
     //this is class will contain methods like:
     //public abstract IDbConnection CreateConnectionInstance();
}

public class SqlDb : Db
{
     //this is class will contain methods like:
     //public override IDbConnection CreateConnectionInstance()
     //{
     //      ... return new SqlConnection();
     //}
}

public class OracleDb : Db
{

}

public class MockupDb : Db
{

}

//this class generates the fitting provider but does not have a base (is this correct?)
public static class DbFactory
{
    public static Db CreateInstance(DbProviderType dbProviderType)
    {
        Db db = null;
        switch (dbProviderType)
        {
            case DbProviderType.Oracle:
                db = new OracleDb();
                break;
            case DbProviderType.Sql:
                db = new SqlDb();
                break;
            case DbProviderType.Mockup:
                db = new MockupDb();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return db;
    }
}
```

So my questions in short:
1) Is this a correct implementation of the abstract factory pattern?
2) What can be done better?
3) What is the advantage towards different repository classes which inherit from a base class?

Thx a lot guys.

If you need more information on my code please tell me. But there is no more at this point of time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstract db provider factory already exist in .Net. Its called [DbProviderFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbproviderfactory.aspx). You can create different concrete factories via

```
var factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("System.Data.OracleClient");
DbConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection();
```

Why not to use what is already in box?

[Here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/amit_agrl/ProviderFactory08052005030042AM/ProviderFactory.aspx) you can read more about DbProviderFactories and how to add custom factory implementations.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you mixed some concepts.

Repository allows you abstract away from the storage nature. It's a black box, which can give you an object, matching some criteria, and take it back. Repository internals can get or store object in multiple data sources (e. g. some object data stored in database, another part of data - in file, or in an external device, which cannot be described in terms of relational data source).

Factory can add more flexibility when working with ADO .NET data sources. But it is not a substitute of the repository. Repository can use factory to get particular data source implementation.

Upd. About your code sample - factory should throw exception, when provider's type is unknown.